# Invert some values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this one:

```
ID   |   Description  |  Account  |  DepAccount  |  Value
----------------------------------------------------------
0    |  Something     | 110       | 0            | 500,50
1    |  Something x   | 0         | 110          | -320,95
```

Now I need a query to sum the values but there is an issue with it.

Like in the example, if the account is 110, it is fine, if the `DepAccount` is 110, I need to invert the value so I sum 320,95 instead of -320,95

So the query should return value: 821,45

So something like:

```
SELECT SUM(Value) As Total 
FROM Table 
WHERE Account = 110 OR DepAccount = 110 WHERE etc...
```

Who can help? I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express Edition

Comment: What should happen if Account or DepAccount are something other than 110? What if they are both set?

Comment: Do you always want to invert the value when the DepAccount = 110? So that if Value is 100,20 and DepAccount = 110 you would add -100,20.

Comment: No I only want to invert when the depaccount is 110

Comment: ow and also, if the value is positive, I need to sum the negative value. So as an example: if Depaccount = 110 and Value = 500 I need -500, so always invert the value if depaccount = 110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample set is small so it's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but it sounds something like this:

```
SELECT
  sum(case
        when Account = 110 then Value
        when DepAccount = 100 then -1 * Value
        else 0
      end)
from MyTable
```

That assumes that "invert" means "reverse the sign". If you only need to make negatives positive, use

```
SELECT
  sum(case
        when Account = 110 then Value
        when DepAccount = 100 then abs(Value)
        else 0
      end)
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(ABS(Value)) As Total FROM Table WHERE Account = 110 OR DepAccount = 110 WHERE etc
```

that should get you what you need.  the abs function returns the absolute value of the number.

Comment: Abs will always make it positive (which may be what is wanted here) but it does not "invert it", if it was positive it will remain positive, rather than reversing to negative.

Comment: @pstrjds, based on his question, he didn't really want inversion.  he told us he wanted the sum to be 821,45, which means all numbers should be read as positive.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying, but could you do this:

```
select sum(abs(Value)) as Total
    from Table
    where Account = 110
        or DepAccount = 110
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  one of Account and DepAccount  is always 0, you can write

```
SELECT 
CASE 
 WHEN DepAccount = 0 THEN Account
 WHEN Account = 0  THEN DepAccount
END AS acct,
SUM(abs(Value)) AS Total
FROM Table
GROUP BY 
 CASE 
 WHEN DepAccount = 0 THEN Account
 WHEN Account = 0  THEN DepAccount
END
```